# Android Studio "error decompressing data!corrupted installer"

Tags: android-studio

First there was error NSIS error at the start off installation then after resolving that problem during installation after 8% it is showing
"error decompressing data!corrupted installer".How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's may be due to pausing your download while downloading studio in IDM. try again with newly downloaded studio